# Google Chrome Cookies: What determines what cookies are sent?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I found the following cookies being sent over by my Chrome browser with each being assigned some random value.  What are all these cookies and what determines that they should be set as a request property? Is everybody's the same?

```
_gid
_gcl 
_fbp
_omappvp=
__utma=
__utmz
AMCV_F5237FF95824E58%40AdobeOrg=
_mibhv=
AAMC_aaanortheast_0=REGION%7C7; 
aam_uuid=
mbox=
s_fid=61AFA328A2-195F2F36B861E226; 
AMCV_CB586B85500101%40AdobeOrg=
__utmzzses
```

Comment: How and where did you get that cookie data? Any network packet captureing tool? Cookies data depends on that specific website.

Comment: Got this info using http fiddler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These cookies can come from various websites. The assigned values are usually
encoded in some manner and are not random.

They are called by Wikipedia
[HTTP cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
and are defined as:

> An HTTP cookie (also called web cookie, Internet cookie, browser cookie, or simply cookie) is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored on the user's computer by the user's web browser while the user is browsing. Cookies were designed to be a reliable mechanism for websites to remember stateful information (such as items added in the shopping cart in an online store) or to record the user's browsing activity (including clicking particular buttons, logging in, or recording which pages were visited in the past). They can also be used to remember arbitrary pieces of information that the user previously entered into form fields such as names, addresses, passwords, and credit card numbers.

Cookies that are set by some website are automatically included with any
web-request that you do on that website. The browser will automatically include
them with the request, to be processed by the receiving website.
The cookies set by one website are usually not sent when surfing other
websites.

Some research done on your list of cookies:

- `_gid` may come from [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/cookie-usage)
  but also from the next point.
- The [Mott MacDonald Group](https://www.mottmac.com/cookies)
  may be responsible for quite a few:
  `_gid`,
  `_omappvp`,
  `__utma`,
  `__utmz`.
- [Adobe Cloud](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid_cookies.html)
  may be responsible for the `AMCV` cookies.
- If you visited a
  [Pandora](https://uk.pandora.net/en/cookie-policy/cookie-policy.html)
  website, they might be responsible for the `mibhv` cookie.

Most cookies can only be identified within the context of the website
that created them, and this information should also be available
when you are listing them.

If in doubt you could use
[Cookiepedia](https://cookiepedia.co.uk/).
But searching for example for
[mbox](https://cookiepedia.co.uk/cookies/mbox)
finds:

---

[image]

---

The context website is then the most informative information when identifying the
provenance of a cookie.

Sometimes some cookies should be cleaned out, for example if the website
that stored in them its login credentials were corrupted.
This happened most to me with Google websites.

You would also clean them out if you don't wish some other person to be
logged-in automatically to websites while using your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies have values created by code executed at the web server your browser is connected to.

Taking the list above:

```
_gid - Google
_gcl - Google
_fbp - Facebook
_omappvp= - 
__utma= - Google
__utmz - Google
AMCV_F5237FF95824E58%40AdobeOrg= - Adobe
_mibhv= 
AAMC_aaanortheast_0=REGION%7C7; - Adobe
aam_uuid= - Adobe
mbox= - Adobe
s_fid=61AFA328A2-195F2F36B861E226; - Adobe
AMCV_CB586B85500101%40AdobeOrg= - Adobe
__utmzzses - Google
```

Mostly these are used for advertising, tracking and analytics purposes.  Often the cookie has a "campaign" identifier which companies assign and use to measure the success of their advertising campaigns.

Hope that helps.